# Which table does store the Sitecore Recycle Bin items?

Tags: sitecore-client

I would like to see the items moved to recycle bin.

In which database table, can we see the items details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under your `Master database` you can find the items into `[dbo].[ArchivedItems]` table.

The table looks like this.

[image]

So if you delete an item. It will create an entry into this.

Here is the Database query for this.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [RowId]
      ,[ArchivalId]
      ,[ItemId]
      ,[Name]
      ,[TemplateID]
      ,[MasterID]
      ,[ParentID]
      ,[Created]
      ,[Updated]
  FROM [sitecore10.2_Master].[dbo].[ArchivedItems]
```

If you want to see, who deleted this item, then you can check the table called `[dbo].[Archive]`.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [ArchivalId]
      ,[ItemId]
      ,[ParentId]
      ,[Name]
      ,[OriginalLocation]
      ,[ArchiveDate]
      ,[ArchivedBy]
      ,[ArchiveName]
  FROM [sitecore10.2_Master].[dbo].[Archive]
```

Take the `ArchivalId` from `ArchivedItems` table and search in the `Archive` table using the same. And you will get the details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I have looked this table. But don't see the column for user who deleted this item. Is there any table having that reference?

Comment: @Astle Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted items can be found in `Archive` table in the master db. Try this query.

> SELECT *  FROM [SC93_Master].[dbo].[Archive] order by [ArchiveDate] desc

**Recycle bin**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Hope it helps!